# How can I "throw" inside "catch" method from a rejected promise to be handled by an outer "catch" bock?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch, throw

**This is working !**

```js
function rejectedPromise() {
  return Promise.reject("ERROR");
}

async function someFunction() {
  try {
    rejectedPromise()
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));   // IT WORKS ! THE ERROR IS BEING LOGGED HERE
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

someFunction();
```

---

**This is not.**

```js
function rejectedPromise() {
  return Promise.reject("ERROR");
}

async function someFunction() {
  try {
    rejectedPromise()
    .catch((err) => { throw err; });      // CAN'T I THROW HERE ?
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);                     // DOES NOT WORK. THE ERROR SHOULD BE LOGGED HERE
  }
}

someFunction();
```

**QUESTION**

Why?

Note: my goal is to `throw` the error from the `catch` method of the rejected Promise and `throw` it so it's handled by an outer `catch` block. Don't know if it matters, but this is happening inside an `async` function (it doesn't work if I remove the `async` keyword from the example anyways).

**EXTRA:**

In Node, I'm getting this (even though there's a catch block):

> **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:** Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with
>   .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: You should probably use `await` if you want to use `try/catch`. The `.catch()` is a Promise API thing. If Promise chains would actually bomb out with errors, then the whole promise chain construct would be useless.

Comment: Right. It’s either `.catch`, which is the “promise async exception handler”, *or* `try..await..catch`, which is the syntactic sugar around the former to make it look more synchronous. You can’t combine both approaches.

Comment: Didn't know that. I really thought I could mix them around. Thank you both.

Comment: Well, if you could, then what happens with this: `promise.then(a).then(b).then(c).then(d).then(e)`. If, say, `b` throws then you need to handle it. But also `c` or `d` can throw. You'd either have to surround the entire chain in `try/catch` and try and figure out how to recover (not trivial) or alternatively, surround each link in the chain with `try/catch` which is a lot of noise. It's also bad if you *can* recover from a problem and want to continue the chain.

Comment: @VLAZ makes total sense. Thanks again for this info.

Comment: As for the "why": the `try..catch` code is executing *now* synchronously, the `.then`/`.catch` happens *sometime later* when the promise resolves. The code will be long outside the `try..catch` context by that time.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, there is no need for using `.catch()` if you are inside an `async` function. I don't know why you want nested `try...catch`, but it looks like this would achieve what you want:

```
function rejectedPromise() {
  return Promise.reject("ERROR");
}

async function someFunction() {
  try {
    try {
      await rejectedPromise()
    } 
    catch(err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

someFunction();
```