# Every thrown error ends up in catch block even tho it has to thrown error before that and stop the rest of the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

```
    async deleteUser(userId: string): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
    const userToDelete = await userModel.findByIdAndDelete(userId)
    if(!userToDelete) {
        throw new Error(`User with id: ${userId} does not exist`)
    }
    return true
    } catch {
        throw new Error("Something wrong with the database");
    }
}
```

Wanted result:

1. If UserId is valid but non-existing in DB throw first error
2. If UserId is not valid or any other type of error throw second error

Current result:

1. If UserId is valid but non-existing in DB throw SECOND error
2. If UserId is not valid or any other type of error throw second error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I "throw" inside "catch" method from a rejected promise to be handled by an outer "catch" bock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667147/how-can-i-throw-inside-catch-method-from-a-rejected-promise-to-be-handled-by)

Answer (score 2):

Well you're `throw`ing an exception inside a `try` block, which will be caught, and your `catch` block then re-throws a different exception. You can either inspect the caught exception

```
async deleteUser(userId: string): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
        const userToDelete = await userModel.findByIdAndDelete(userId)
        if (!userToDelete) {
            throw new Error(`User with id: ${userId} does not exist`)
        }
        return true
    } catch(e) {
        if (e.message == `User with id: ${userId} does not exist`) throw e
        else throw new Error("Something wrong with the database")
    }
}
```

<sup>(Checking an `e.code` you put on the error with `Object.assign`, or testing for an `Error` subclass with `instanceof`, would be nicer than testing the message)</sup>

or put the `try` closer around the `await …` statement whose errors you want to handle:

```
async deleteUser(userId: string): Promise<boolean> {
    let userToDelete
    try {
        userToDelete = await userModel.findByIdAndDelete(userId)
    } catch {
        throw new Error("Something wrong with the database");
    }
    if (!userToDelete) {
        throw new Error(`User with id: ${userId} does not exist`)
    }
    return true
}
```

which is [nicer with `.catch()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664037/1048572):

```
async deleteUser(userId: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const userToDelete = await userModel.findByIdAndDelete(userId).catch(e => {
        throw new Error("Something wrong with the database");
    })
    if (!userToDelete) {
        throw new Error(`User with id: ${userId} does not exist`)
    }
    return true
}
```